# Find complex numbers in polynomial

Tags: calculus

Find complex numbers $c_0$, $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that the polynomial
$$P (z) = z^3 + c_2z^2 + c_1z + c_0$$
the three roots are
$$z = i, z = 1 + 5i,z = -2$$

Answer (score 0):

If $z=z_{1}$ and $z=z_{2}, z=z_{3}$ are the roots of Given Complex polynomial $P(z)$

Then Using factor theorem $z-z_{1}$ and $z-z_{2}$ are $z-z_{3}$ are the roots of $p(z) =0$

Where $z_{1},z_{2},z_{3}\in \mathbb{C}$

So $P(z) = (z-z_{1})\cdot (z-z_{2})\cdot (z-z_{3})$

above $P(z) = z^3+c_{2}z^2+c_{1}z+c_{0}$ and $z_{1} =i\;,z_{2} =1+5i\;,z_{3}=-2$

Comment: Notice, Substituting, in turn, all three roots z=i, z=1+5i & z=−2 in the given equation P(z)=z3+c2z2+c1z+c0, one gets three linear equations as follows
c2−ic1−c0=−i           (1)
2(12−5i)c2−(1+5i)c1−c0=−2(37+55i)    (2)
4c2−2c1+c0=8       (3)
adding (1) & (3), one gets
5c2−(2+i)c1=8−i       (4)
adding (2) & (3), one gets
2(14−5i)c2−(3+5i)c1=−2(33+55i)     (5)

i have come so far, now im stuck